# Case Sensitive where query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am creating a login form and I want the password to be case sensistive. I wrote the following code. How can I make it case sensitive using the where clause.

```
PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(" select * from user where userid =? and   password   =?" );

stm.setString(1, userid);
stm.setString(2, pswd);        
ResultSet rs =stm.executeQuery();
if (!rs.next()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Invalid Id/Password");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the **other better suggestion** , one thing you can try is to use the [`BINARY` OPERATOR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-op.html)  ,  which will force MySQL to check for an exact case.

```
select * from user where userid=?  and BINARY  password=?
```

IMHO , [Martijn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17989842/1163607) is the one you should follow.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the password should be hashed (at least!) with functions like `sha1`. `Sha1` returns a whole other value for different capitals.

If you have case insensative results, you probally are saving it plain text, which should be altered FIRST THING!

```
String  - sha1 value
example - c3499c2729730a7f807efb8676a92dcb6f8a3f8f  
Example - 0f01ed56a1e32a05e5ef96e4d779f34784af9a96  
eXample - decb1226835e95f0441ec4ee0ecd9283796a9cfb
```

You can also change you DB column to `utf8_general`* instead of `utf8_general_ci`*, ci means CaseInsentative. But you really dont want to do this way
**Asuming you use utf8*

---

I dont know the functions available in java, but the principles stay the same. I suggest you do some research about how to store passwords using java :)

Comment: For passwords I'd suggest to use a stronger and 'more secure' hash like pbkdf2, bcrypt or scrypt

Comment: Ah `pbkdf2`, I was looking for that one yesterday, forgot the name. You are right, but its more about the principle in my post. +1

Answer (score 2):

Storing password in plain text is a bad idea. Use md5 hashing at least.

Comment: No, sha1 at least :) md5 should be considered breakable to those with a reasonable amount of time

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am a beginner, would keep in mind next time :)